# msaccess - sql view - autocomplete / intellisense or alternate way to write queries?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ssms

I have a bit of experience with SQL (still learning), but I want to start using MSAccess.

I'm wondering if there is a better way to write SQL (without using design view) then using the SQL View as it doesn't have auto-complete / intellisense.

I was thinking that I could connect it to SQL server management studio, but I'd be able to write the query and then be able to keep it within the MSAccess database.

Thanks.

Comment: SQL server management studio would be the good choice if you want to learn more SQL

Comment: @Zsuzsa - That would help to learn T-SQL, but the resulting queries will not necessarily work under other SQL dialects like Access SQL.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: No, there isn't.

But; a quick google reveals some third party utilities that claim to make developing SQL queries easier - to be honest, I doubt they're very good. The reason for my doubt, is that the way MS Access databases are "built" as a file is very different to most bigger database systems. Bigger systems like MySql and MS SQL make it very easy to get the schema of the tables you are working with, so utilities can get this schema as you are working and show it to you in the form of Intellisense.

However, what I used to do when I was maintaining some legacy MS Access "Applications" was to use a text editor like Notepad++, which has some rudimentary autocomplete functionality, as well as SQL syntax highlighting. Far from perfect, but it got the job done.

Comment: In did do many a Google search and couldn'tfind anything specific to MS Access. Like you pointed out there are tools for other systems but having to use another editor seems counterproductive. It is actually what I am using now as undo doesn't work properly in SQL view.

Comment: This is the kind of thing I had in mind: http://razorsql.com/features/access_editor.html but really, they're not that great in my experience.

Comment: I used to create C# applications that had legacy MS Access backends to try and get away from whole "applications" created in MS Access (as they are not easily extensible), and the problem showed itself there too. I experimented with various IDEs and considered creating my own, but really, Notepad++ and Sublime text editor ended up working the best for me.

Comment: i thought I would ask as a separate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31950497/msaccess-storing-sql-query-in-external-file