# msaccess - storing sql query in external file

Tags: sql, ms-access, external

I dislike the built in text editor for MsAccess and would like to use an external text editor.

Expanding on a previous question: [msaccess - sql view - autocomplete / intellisense or alternate way to write queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31876712/msaccess-sql-view-autocomplete-intellisense-or-alternate-way-to-write-quer)

Is there a way I can store the sql query in an external file and have MsAccess reference it?

Comment: Access does not support the capability to use SQL statements stored in external files.

Comment: you would have to use VBA to open your file, read your sql, and set that sql to the .sql property of a querydef object, then save the querydef in your database.

Answer (score 1):

If you are OK with setting the recordsource via VBA, then you can use this:

```
Public Function ReadTxt(filePath As String) As String

    Dim oFSO As FileSystemObject
    Set oFSO = New FileSystemObject

    Dim oFS As TextStream

    If oFSO.FileExists(filePath) Then

        On Error GoTo Err

        Set oFS = oFSO.OpenTextFile(filePath)
        ' read file
        ReadTxt = oFS.ReadAll
        'Debug.Print IIf(oFS Is Nothing, "file is closed", "file opened")
        oFS.Close
    Else
        MsgBox "The file path is invalid.", vbCritical, vbNullString
        Exit Function
    End If

    Exit Function

Err:
    MsgBox "Error while reading the file.", vbCritical, vbNullString
    oFS.Close
    Exit Function

End Function
```

Usage: `ReadTxt("C:\TempFolder\YourQuery.txt")`

However, it's a lot of fiddling around, why not just cut and paste it (the SQL) into Access?